# url in routes.php not rendering in laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel-4

I am new to laravel. I am just trying to do some basic stuff using routes and controllers. 
I have this controller named testcontroller which looks as below

```
<?php
class testcontroller extends BaseController{
public function show(){
return 'test';
}

}
```

I have also defined a route in routes.php as below

```
Route::get('test', 'testcontroller@show');
```

when i try to access it using localhost/laravel/public/test it would give the 404 NOT FOUND error, however i have tried rewriting the route in main directory as

```
Route::get('/', 'testcontroller@show');
```

and it works all fine, i have even tried and successfully rendered views using this. Can anyone suggest where am i going wrong with the url. Any help will be appreciated. 
Thanks :)

Comment: Did you run `composer dump` after creating the controller?

Comment: I did it now, but its still throwing the same error

Comment: When you are not using Route::resource(), you better pass an array as a second argument to Route::get('test',array('uses'=>'TestController@showTest'));
It doesn't answer why is your route working when pointing your root.
Also try to keep the Laravel name conventions as they are with capitals, camel case etc.

Comment: actually i was doing like that only before, that didn't work so i tried doing like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test controller

```
# app/controllers/TestController.php

class TestController extends BaseController {

    public function show()
    {
        return 'test';
    }
}
```

Routes File

```
# app/routes.php

Route::get('test', array(
    'uses' => 'TestController@show'
));

Route::get('/', array(
    'uses' => 'TestController@show'
));
```

**Edit:** since that is not working, it is probably to do with your server configuration. Instead of learning how to do that, I'd recommend the use of a VM over WAMP. Also Laravel provides an easy way to use one with [Laravel Homestead](http://laravel.com/docs/homestead).

Check out [this instructional video](https://laracasts.com/series/build-a-laravel-app-from-scratch/episodes/1) on how to do that.

Comment: tried doing that but to no avail, still giving the same error.
I fear that i  have some error in configuration or installation of the laravel

Comment: @Gaurav how are you serving?

Comment: wamp serever with
apache 2.4.9
php 5.5.12
on a windows 8 64 bit machine

Comment: @Gaurav It is probably Apache configuration. Instead of learning that, you should try learning how to use Laravel Homestead for serving locally. Check the video link in the answer.

Comment: Otherwise, maybe double check your vhosts, and overrides in apache